# When can we have mod elections - or - a vote of no confidence

Tags: discussion, moderators

So, weren't we supposed to choose our mods near the end of the beta?

What's the status of this first class Stack Exchange feature?

Comment: Elections won't turn this site into anarchy as you wish.

Comment: Expect few glitches, they are doing a pretty good job I think. However I agree that they are not enough and two or three additional moderators may help.

Comment: @Pierre: New moderators is coming now.

Comment: @Pierre 303: I think that this question alludes to the point that some people disagree with your first statement. I would be one of those people.

Comment: @SnOrfus: I suppose existing mods will not be re-elected by default. If they propose themselves again, I'll upvote both bigown & chris. To summarize my view: I think they did some mistakes, like the ones you and I do everyday. We are all humans after all. If you compare those mistakes to the work they provided for us, for free and with pleasure, they are just "glitches". I believe those glitches happened because we had only 2 active moderators on different tz. With 5 or 6 of them, they will be able to talk to each other and make better decisions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mod elections will be held in the new year, though it make take a month or two -- we have a lot of sites that we need to run elections on and the election code is just out of beta

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/

Comment: Thanks, and can we be certain that elections won't cause anarchy as I wish?

Comment: Will the elections be publicized on the main site or should we all be keeping a close eye on meta?

Comment: @anna there are multiple site messages and a per-user message to eligible (>150 rep) uses once the final election starts. Oh, and a post on meta too.